# LUA - IsMouseButtonPressed not working properly for G buttons

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I am using a G700 mouse and I'm trying to write a rapidfire LUA script. I'm having trouble assigning the IsMouseButtonPressed to any other mouse button then 1,2,3.
How can I use IsMouseButtonPressed onto G4 mouse button?

Working...

```
if IsMouseButtonPressed(2) then
   OutputLogMessage("Mouse button 2 pressed") 
end
```

NOT Working...

```
if IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
   OutputLogMessage("Mouse button 4 pressed") 
end
```

I need this function while I'm right clicking.

Script

```
    ----------------------------------------------Simple settings----------------------------------------------
    REEcoil=1000
    Sensrelative=REEcoil/1000
    ---------------------------Rapidfire---------------------------
    PressSpeedMin=15            --Change this           <-this is the delay between pressing and releasing left click
    PressSpeedMax=25            --Change this
            
    NoRecoilRFMin=3         --Change this           <-this is recoil reduction
    NoRecoilRFMax=5         --Change this
        
     
    SleepNRFMin=75          --Change this           <-this is the delay between clicks
    SleepNRFMax=105         --Change this
            
    ------------------------------------------------------BINDS------------------------------------------------------

        LCRF=1              --just leftclick
    RC=3                    --just rightclick
    Rapidfirebutton=4       -- tis my forward key for thumb use >>> if I put RapidFireButton to 2 then it's working fine. How can I make it work with my thumb button?
       
 
    ------------------------------------------------------FUNCTIONS------------------------------------------------------   
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);   
     
function RapidFire()    
        
    OutputLogMessage("Running RapidFire function")
    
        repeat
        OutputLogMessage("Mousebutton " .. Rapidfirebutton .. " clicked. \n")               
        PressMouseButton(LCRF)
            Sleep(math.random(PressSpeedMin,PressSpeedMax))
            ReleaseMouseButton(LCRF)
            MoveMouseRelative(0,math.random(NoRecoilRFMin,NoRecoilRFMax)*Sensrelative)
            Sleep(math.random(SleepNRFMin,SleepNRFMax)) 
            MoveMouseRelative(0,math.random(NoRecoilRFMin,NoRecoilRFMax)*Sensrelative)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(Rapidfirebutton)
end    

 ------------------------------------------------------Main function------------------------------------------------------
function OnEvent(event, arg)    

    if GetMKeyState() == 3 then
     
        OutputLogMessage("Script active.".. "\n")

        if IsMouseButtonPressed(RC)then                 --Loop for ADS. Primes rapidfire
                OutputLogMessage("Weapon primed \n")                             
                
            repeat
                    if IsMouseButtonPressed(Rapidfirebutton)  then              
                    OutputLogMessage("Call function RapidFire \n")
                    RapidFire   ()
                    Sleep(20) -- added after comment by EGOR
                end
             until not IsMouseButtonPressed(RC)             --end of Priming loop
          end
    end
end
```

Comment: `IsMouseButtonPressed` works only for buttons 1-5 having binding to default action (for example, MB#4 must have action "Back").  And you must insert `Sleep(15)` inside `OnEvent` before first invocation of `IsMouseButtonPressed`.  If this does not fix your problem, post the whole script.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff It's not working. I have already a sleep period in my script. If I run my script with Mousbutton 2 it's working. But I can't get the G4 button to work. I Post my script in the question section.

Comment: `Rapidfirebutton=4 -- tis my forward key for thumb use` But "forward" key is MB#5, not 4.  Set to 5 if you want to use "forward" mouse button.

Comment: `Sleep(20)` should be inserted at the first line of `OnEvent` body.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff 
When i view the event of the mouse button I get the following result:

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, arg)
end

Log:
event = MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED, arg = 4
event = MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED, arg = 4

I did insert the sleep timer. The result is the same. if I set the RapidFireButton to 4 it wont be recognized. as if "Mouse Butten Pressed, arg 4" <> "IsMouseButtonPressed(4)". Any idea?

Comment: You probably have wrong binding at MB#4.  Please show the screenshot of your bindings like [this one](https://itnews2day.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/logitech-optical-gaming-mouse.jpg)